# Using natvis with template parameter packs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, natvis

I have a data structure that looks roughly like this

```cpp
struct Column
{
    void* data;
};

template <class... T>
struct Table
{
    size_t count;
    std::vector<Column> columns; // columns.size() == sizeof...(T)
};
```

and I'm trying to visualize it in the following way

```
+ Table
  + Column 0
      item 1
      item 2
      ...
  + Column 1
      item 1
      item 2
      ...
```

This is what I have so far:

```xml
<Type Name="Table&lt;*&gt;">
    <Expand>
        <Synthetic Name="Column 0">
            <Expand>
                <ArrayItems>
                    <Size>count</Size>
                    <ValuePointer>($T1*) columns[0].data</ValuePointer>
                </ArrayItems>
            </Expand>
        </Synthetic>

        <Synthetic Name="Column 1" Condition="columns.size() > 1">
            <Expand>
                <ArrayItems>
                    <Size>count</Size>
                    <ValuePointer>($T2*) columns[1].data</ValuePointer>
                </ArrayItems>
            </Expand>
        </Synthetic>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

Obviously, this scales really poorly. I'm relegated to copy-pasting the code for each column and adding a `Condition` to enable or disable it. I'll end up with a maximum number of supported columns after which point the visualization just stops showing columns.

Is there some way to display this more intelligently? I can imagine a couple ways to do it if I could index the template parameter with an expression like `$T$i`.

What I really want to do is something like this:

```xml
<Type Name="Table&lt;*&gt;">
    <Expand>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>columns.size()</Size>
            <Value>
                <Synthetic Name="Column %i">
                <Expand>
                    <ArrayItems>
                        <Size>count</Size>
                        <ValuePointer>($T$i2*) columns[$i2].data</ValuePointer>
                    </ArrayItems>
                </Expand>
            </Synthetic>
            </Value>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

Comment: I think your problem isn't with natvis, you're trying to reimplement the tuple.
As for `$T$i` - natvis is very simple, and `$T1`, `$T2` ... - are only macros

Comment: Maybe using Synthetic in this way is not a good idea, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Synthetic_Item_expansion)...

Comment: No, I'm not trying to reimplement the tuple. Different use case. Different implementation.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I can't tell why it's a bad idea from reading those docs. It appears to be the intended tool for creating additional hierarchy. I want to show an expansion for each column in the table.

Comment: Maybe you can also consider doing this with a bunch of condition statements and then hardcoding for different lengths. Of course there’d be a limit to the number you could show then. Something like: <Type Name=”Table<T>”>
   <DisplayString Condition=”size=1”>[{this.m_ptr[0]}]/>
   <DisplayString Condition=”size=2”>[{this.m_ptr[0]}] [{this.m_ptr[1]}]/>
   <DisplayString Condition=”size>2”>[{this.m_ptr[0]}] [{this.m_ptr[1]}]…/>
</Type>
 But glad to know you've found a workaround for your issue, you can mark it to share the useful info :)

Comment: Yup, that's precisely what's in the in the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the only choice is to make a helper type in code that does recursive template expansion to peel off the template parameters one by one. *And* you have to force the compiler to instantiate the template so it's available for the natvis to use.

The data I'm starting with

```cpp
struct ColumnStorage
{
    void* data;
};

struct TableStorage
{
    size_t rowCount;
    std::vector<ColumnStorage> columns;
};

template <class Table, class... TableColumns>
struct TableAccessor
{
    TableStorage* tableStorage;
};
```

And this is what I needed to add to get decent natvis

```cpp
// The helper type that allows natvis to work. The first template parameter keeps track of the
// column index so we know where to index into TableStorage::columns. The second parameter isn't
// used here. The third parameter is the concrete types of each column.
template <int i, class Table, class... TableColumns>
struct NatvisColumnView;

template <class Table, class... TableColumns>
struct TableAccessor
{
    TableStorage* tableStorage;

    // Used by natvis to cast `this`
    using NatvisView = NatvisColumnView<0, Table, TableColumns...>;

    // Force the compiler to instantiate the template or it won't be available to natvis
    TableAccessor() { (NatvisView*) this; }
};

// End the template recursion. Inherit from TableAccessor so that tableStorage can be used
template <int i, class Table, class Column>
struct NatvisColumnView<i, Table, Column> : TableAccessor<Table, Column> {};

// Recursive template to peel off column types one-by-one
template <int i, class Table, class FirstColumn, class... RestColumns>
struct NatvisColumnView<i, Table, FirstColumn, RestColumns...> : NatvisColumnView<i + 1, Table, RestColumns...>
{
    using base = typename NatvisColumnView<i + 1, Table, RestColumns...>;
};
```

```xml
<Type Name="TableAccessor&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>Table</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
    <Item Name="Count">tableStorage->rowCount</Item>
    <!-- Cast `this` to the view type and use the for visualization -->
    <ExpandedItem>*(NatvisView*) this</ExpandedItem>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<!-- Bottom out the recursive view -->
<Type Name="NatvisColumnView&lt;*,*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>NatvisColumnView</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
    <Synthetic Name="Column">
        <Expand>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>tableStorage->rowCount</Size>
            <ValuePointer>($T3*) tableStorage->columns[$T1].data</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
        </Expand>
    </Synthetic>
    </Expand>
</Type>

<!-- Display the first column then recurse -->
<Type Name="NatvisColumnView&lt;*,*,*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>NatvisColumnView</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
    <Synthetic Name="Column">
        <Expand>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>tableStorage->rowCount</Size>
            <!-- Show the correct column using the column index (first template parameter)
                 and the column type (third template parameter) -->
            <ValuePointer>($T3*) tableStorage->columns[$T1].data</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
        </Expand>
    </Synthetic>
    <ExpandedItem>*(base*) this</ExpandedItem>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

And it ends up looking something like this:
[image]
[image]

I tried various other approaches such as:

- Using IndexListItems. Doesn't work without being able to index the template parameters `$T$i`.
- Using CustomListItems. Again, doesn't work without being able to index template parameters.
- Using a variable templates in TableAccessor to get the type and index. Apparently natvis can't access variable templates.

In the future, I'd go straight to a natvis DLL rather than fussing with the severely limited XML.

Comment: What does a "NatVis DLL" mean? Is it possible to write variable visualization for Visual Studio in C++ and make a DLL by building it?